# Colouring a particular class

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()
```

If I want to colour a particular class, let us say 2 seater, what is the modification in the code

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can wrap the logical condition directly inside `colour` element:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = (class=='2seater'))) + 
  geom_point()+
  labs(color='class')+
  scale_color_discrete(labels=c('TRUE'='2seater','FALSE'='other'))
```

Output:

[image]

As legend will not have a fashion title, you can use `labs()` to change that or follow the pretty smart advice from **@r2evans** creating a new column to store the results of the logical condition using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#Code2
mpg %>% mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000"))+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',aes(group=1),show.legend = F)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just about to post, was preferring to pre-define a new column so that the legend would be more readable.

Comment: @r2evans That is a nice approach dear, you can use labs. I will add that in few seconds!

Comment: mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point()+
scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000"))

to this I am trying to add a trendline which is for all categories because , if I add a trendline geom_smooth(method="lm"), it draws for 2 seater separately which I dont want

Comment: @DipojjalSaha I have added an update for what you want let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding specific colors this way too:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point() +
scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000"))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 7 needed but only 2 provided.`. Did you change `mpg$class` before plotting it? (I'm assuming you're using Duck's data?)

Comment: You have to add the code with the mpg%>%code